# Java equivalent of microtime

Tags: java, math, time

I did some searching and it didn't really return anything.

But I'm trying to replicate PHP's `microtime()` function in Java. I found some articles like [this one](http://jeffrey-kohn.com/code/javascript-equivalent-phps-microtime) that discusses how to achieve it in Javascript. Their logic is flawed though and the msec value of microtime would always return 0. This is what I have so far...

```
    long mstime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long seconds = mstime / 1000;

    double decimal = (mstime - (seconds * 1000)) / 1000;`

    System.out.println(decimal + " " + seconds);
```

Except for no matter what, the decimal portion of the function (msec equivalent of php) will ALWAYS return 0 due to the formula. I'm stuck, confused, and need help.

Fixed code:

```
long mstime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long seconds = mstime / 1000;
double decimal = (mstime - (seconds * 1000)) / 1000d;
return decimal + " " + seconds;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`(mstime - (seconds * 1000))` is a `long`, which you divide by 1000, resulting in 0 (long).

To get floating point precision, either cast to `double`, or divide by a `double` value:

```
double decimal = (mstime - (seconds * 1000)) / 1000d; // note the d
```

By the way, if you need a **higher precision for durations** (time deltas), use `System.nanoTime()`.

`System.currentTimeMillis()` is not that accurate, and will (depending on the platform) not increase in unit increments (1ms) as one would expect. For example, on my system (Win7), the value of `System.currentTimeMillis()` changes every 15 to 16 ms.

Comment: Thank you! I've been bashing my head against a wall since last night trying to figure this out. I'll accept your answer in 5 minutes, it says I have to wait.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
long mstime = System.currentTimeMillis();
float seconds = mstime / 1000;
float decimal = (mstime - (seconds * 1000)) / 1000;
System.out.println(decimal + " " + seconds);
```

I tried it and gave me output as:

```
131.072 1.38548314E9
```

Comment: The output is similar to `131.072 1.38548326E9`. I believe PHP's microtime the first segment msec will be less than 1.